# NPE while casting in ternary operator

Tags: java, casting, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

I am trying to cast `Object` to `Character` in the ternary operator, but if object is `null`, I get NPE. But in general if I cast object, which is `null`, to `Character` it works. So my question is why we can't cast `null` object in ternary operator ?

```
Object[] objs = new Object[3];
        objs[0] = 'A';
        objs[1] = 'C';

        Character case1 = (Character) objs[2]; // ok 
        Character case2 = !Character.valueOf('A').equals(objs[0]) ? 'N' : (Character) objs[2]; // NPE
```

In example above I get NPE in case 2

Comment: `(Character) objs[2]` gets auto-unboxed to `char` because 'N' is a char. You can resolve it with `Character case2 = !Character.valueOf('A').equals(objs[0]) ? (Character) 'N' : (Character) objs[2];`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks a lot. I got it